# AWS ECS Fargate Memory usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I've doubt related to ECS fargate Memory Usage.

- I've created a Task Definition(**0.5vCpu 1GB RAM)** with fargate, and launched it via service.
- I've also created the Cloudwatch Dashboard for monitoring.
- I've seen that when my task is not in use, It uses **10-15%** of Memory, and CPU is almost 0 when not in use.

Can Anyone can explain me? Like is there any Docker master or some daemonset is taking the memory from task Definition.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2):

Your container is running a process that is consuming memory to stay up. When it's not doing anything is pretty normal to see 0 CPU usage and "some" memory usage. I mean if your laptop is doing NOTHING its CPU usage is probably near 0 but memory will be used in the hundreds of MB. Are you expecting to see 0 memory usage? (because that's not how it works)